# How to use @HostBinding with @Input properties in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

(Angular 2 RC4)

With [`@HostBinding`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) we should be able to modify properties of the host, right? My question is, does this apply to [`@Input()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) properties as well and if so, what is the correct usage? If not, is there another way to achieve this?

I made a Plunker here to illustrate my problem: https://embed.plnkr.co/kQEKbT/

Suppose I have a custom component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-img',
  template: `
    <img src="{{src}}">
  `
})
export class CustomImgComponent {
  @Input() src: string;
}
```

And I want to feed the `src` property with an attribute directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[srcKey]'
})
export class SrcKeyDirective implements OnChanges {
  
  @Input() srcKey: string;
  @HostBinding() src;
  
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.src = `https://www.google.com.mt/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/${this.srcKey}_color_272x92dp.png`;
  }
}
```

Why can't this directive change the `[src]` input property of the custom component?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [CustomImgComponent, SrcKeyDirective],
  template: `<custom-img [srcKey]="imageKey"></custom-img>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  imageKey = "googlelogo";
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@HostBinding()` doesn't create property bindings to properties of the host component. That might be worth a bug report though ;-)

I got it working by a workaround with `exportAs` and a template variable but that is quite ugly. https://plnkr.co/edit/TobNVn?p=preview

After some consideration, I think it should work. Otherwise I wouldn't know what `@HostBinding() src;` would do at all.

`@HostBinding('attr.src') src;` or `@HostBinding('class.src') src;` are the more common cases.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I made a bug report here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10499

Comment: This answer has too much text noise, it's a bit unclear what's the solution.

Comment: not applicable in 2021, check Piizei 's answer

Answer (score 118):

You need to combine the decorators like this:

`@HostBinding('class.active') @Input() active: boolean = false;`

Comment: What would I do if my input is an object and I want to bind a property of this object?

Comment: @hugoderhungrige Did you happen to resolve this issue? How to do host binding on a property of an object...

Comment: @RobertKoritnik check my answer, it allows you to use property of an object

Comment: Classic Stack Overflow: scroll to the bottom to find the right answer.

Answer (score 20):

If your `@Input` is an object, you can do:

```
@Input() settings: Settings;

@HostBinding('class.active')
public get isActive(): boolean {
  return this.settings.isActive;
}
```

Comment: Gave me trouble. See [my answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64293469)

Answer (score 6):

1. declare hostbinding property with input property.

   ```
   @HostBinding('attr.aaa') @Input() aaa: boolean = false;
   ```
2. set hostbinding property to input property

   ```
   @Input() aaa: string;
   @HostBinding('attr.bbb') ccc: string;

   ngOnInit(){
     this.ccc = this.aaa;
   }
   ```

Comment: as of Angular 8.2, Hostbinding (in my case: for Angular animation) does work like this: `@HostBinding('@childAnim') @Input() shrink = false;`

Answer (score 3):

```
@Input() appFallback: string;

@HostBinding('attr.src') @Input() src: string;

@HostListener('error') loadFallback(): void {

  if (this.src === this.appFallback) {
    return;
  }
  this.src = this.appFallback;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### BEWARE on using get with hostbinding.

At least I an endless recursion (thousands of cycles). Put a console.log in the get function to check:

```
@HostBinding('@someAnim') get whatever() {
    console.log('#### traffic.....');
    return true;
}
```

I even got that trouble, when just changing some class (so nothing around fancy Angular animation) and not even relying on any other class member whatsoever:

```
@HostBinding('class.foobar') get _____() {
    console.log('#### more traffic.....');
    return true;
}
```

[image]

An addition, it doesn't hurt to have this in your component while developing (as a “free flow canary”):

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('#### more traffic.....');
}
```

You should only see one log entry per, say, state-change and instantiated component, anyway not thousands...

**—At last— I had luck with this one:**

- distinct variable for incoming (@Input) and outgoing (@HostBinding)
- changing the outgoing upon change
- → no „free flow“

```js
    @Input() animTileAttrib = false;
    @HostBinding('@animTile') paramPack: AnimParams = { value: false, params: {}};

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log('#### traffic.....');
        if ('animTileAttrib' in changes) {
            this.paramPack = { value: changes.animTileAttrib.currentValue, params: {} };
        }
    }
```