# Angular 2 Component: Set class on selected element from component scope

Tags: angular

I would like to dynamically generate a string of classes based on the `@Inputs` to my `Component`.

I want these classes to be applied to the element that was selected by the `Component`, not any child elements of the `Component`.

Let's say I have a simple `Component`:

```
@Component({
    selector:       'responsive-table-column',
    templateUrl:    `<div #responsiveTableCell >
                        <ng-content></ng-content>
                    </div>`
})
export class ResponsiveTableColumn {
    private A:string = "";
    private B:string = "";
    @Input()
    get a(){
        return this.A;
    }
    set a(val:any){
        this.A = val;
    }
    @Input()
    get b(){
        return this.B;
    }
    set b(val:any){
        this.B = val;
    }
    getClassName(){
        //Do something to create class names
        return "classes";
    }
}
```

I would like to apply the generated class names to my `<responsive-table-column>` element that has been selected by my component.

How can I access this element? Replace isn't supported, otherwise I would place it on `#responsiveTableCell`.

Essentially, this is what I would like to see:

```
<responsive-table-column class="{{getClassName()}}" >
    <div #responsiveTableCell >
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</responsive-table-column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to use `ElementRef.nativeElement.classList` to enable/disable various classes:

```
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

ngOnChanges() {
  this.elRef.nativeElement.classList.add(this.a); 
}
```

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that (use `.nativeElement`), but I was thinking the same. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `Renderer2` instead if using `nativeElement` directly bothers you. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer2-class.html#!#addClass-anchor. You can also use `@HostBinding('class') classes:String;` and create a string that contains the classes and assign it to `classes` but that doesn't work well together with statically added classes like  `<my-comp class="c1 c2 c3">` AFAIR.

Comment: With `Renderer2` being experimental, I'm not sure how supported it will be in future releases. I have not heard anything about `@HostBinding()` though! That sounds promising! I'm looking at [your answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771403/how-to-use-hostbinding-with-input-properties-in-angular-2) about `@HostBinding`. This sounds like the right route. Is there any reason I shouldn't use `@HostBinding`?

Comment: `@HostBinding` is pergectly fine of course, just usimg it with plain `'class'` is a bit problematic, because if there are other ways used to set classes at the same time this doesn't work well together (other classes will be removed) `@HostBinding('class.foo')` is usually the right way but requires you to know the class names in advance. You can also use `Renderer` until `Renderer2` becomes stable.