# When is combining HostBinding with Input *sometimes* necessary when updating a property

Tags: javascript, angular, decorator

I am trying to understand when I need to use `@HostBinding` and when it must be combined with `@Input` within a directive. Consider I have a directive that replaces a missing image with a default one:

Here is a working version:

*image-fallback.directive.ts*

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appImageFallbackHostBindingAndInput]",
})
export class ImageFallbackDirectiveWithHostBindingAndInput {
  verifiedSrc: string;
  defaultImage = DEFAULT_IMAGE;
  @HostBinding("src") @Input('src') src: string;
  @HostListener("error") onError() {
    this.handleErrorFallback();
  }
  constructor() {}
  handleErrorFallback() {
    // set directly like it is a class property without eg, renderer2
    this.src = this.defaultImage;
  }
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
<img [src]="src" appImageFallbackHostBindingAndInput alt="HostBinding and Input" />
```

Even though this `src` property is not an `@Input` on `AppComponent`, apparently it is still needed here. Why? I thought HostBinding would allow me to bind to a property of its host.

But, even more than that, if you'll look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sahga9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) you'll note that omitting the second `@Input` decorator does in fact work the first time. Just once, but it does allow me to set `this.src = this.defaultImage` like the "completely working" example. So my first thought of like, well I guess you need the Input if you are going to two-way bind or something, doesn't really hold water because apparently it does to some extent work. In fact, I didn't even notice the bug I had using only `HostBinding` until sometime had passed and I noticed updated images weren't always rendering when they errored.

#### When is it necessary to combine these decorators, and why does it work with only `HostBinding` *once*?

---

Note: a few answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771403/how-to-use-hostbinding-with-input-properties-in-angular-2) say that it is necessary, but they don't explain why or in which specific cases it is necessary, or explain why it sometimes works without both.

Answer (score 0):

Without `@Input()` decorator, you are only updating the `src` property of the HTMLImageElement, not the directive. The first version is working because you update the property of the directive, then change it to fall back url, then bind it to HTMLImageElement `src` property. The proper solution should be:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: "[appImageFallbackWithOnlyHostBinding]",
})
export class ImageFallbackDirectiveWithOnlyHostBinding {
  @HostListener("error") onError() {
    this.handleErrorFallback();
  }
  constructor(private el: ElementRef<HTMLImageElement>) {}
  handleErrorFallback() {
    // Prevent infinite loop
    if (this.el.nativeElement.src !== DEFAULT_IMAGE) {
      this.el.nativeElement.src = DEFAULT_IMAGE;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: it takes some time to explain your problem. We'll rename `src` to `directiveSrc` in the directive, and `src` to `appSrc` in the `app.component.ts`, so the first one with `@Input()` becomes:

```html
<img [directiveSrc]="appSrc" appImageFallbackHostBindingAndInput alt="HostBinding and Input" />
```

```js
@Directive({
  selector: "[appImageFallbackHostBindingAndInput]",
})
export class ImageFallbackDirectiveWithHostBindingAndInput {
  defaultImage = DEFAULT_IMAGE;
  @HostBinding("src") @Input() directiveSrc: string;
  @HostListener("error") onError() {
    this.handleErrorFallback();
  }
  handleErrorFallback() {
    this.src = this.defaultImage;
  }
}
```

With `@Input()`, `directiveSrc` is bound to `appSrc`, which will update `src` of HTMLImageElement thanks to `@HostBinding('src')`. If there is an error, we update `directiveSrc` to fallback url, which will update `src` of HTMLImageElement thanks to `@HostBinding('src')`. So it works:

- appSrc = good ==> directiveSrc = good ==> src = good
- appSrc = bad ==> directiveSrc = bad ==> src = bad ==> event error ==> directiveSrc = `bad --> fallback` ==> src = fallback

Now, without `@Input()`, it will become:

```html
<img [src]="appSrc" appImageFallbackWithOnlyHostBinding alt="HostBinding only" />
```

```js
@Directive({
  selector: "[appImageFallbackWithOnlyHostBinding]",
})
export class ImageFallbackDirectiveWithOnlyHostBinding {
  defaultImage = DEFAULT_IMAGE;
  @HostBinding("src") directiveSrc: string;
  @HostListener("error") onError() {
    this.handleErrorFallback();
  }
  handleErrorFallback() {
    // First time: directiveSrc is undefined
    // From second time: directiveSrc is equal this.defaultImage
    this.directiveSrc = this.defaultImage;
  }
}
```

So, without `@Input()` the HTMLImageElement's `src` is bound to `appSrc`, it displays the image. When `appSrc` becomes bad:

- First time: appSrc = bad => src = bad => error event => directiveSrc = `undefined --> fallback` => src = fallback
- From second time: appSrc = bad ==> src = bad ==> error event ==> directiveSrc = `fallback --> fallback`: since there is no change in `directiveSrc`, `src` is not updated.

To overcome it: you need to make `directiveSrc` change in 2 different cycles, such as:

```js
  handleErrorFallback() {
    this.src = undefined;
    setTimeout(() => this.src = this.defaultImage);
  }
```

Of course, I would not recommend either of your solutions, as it is hard to understand. That's why the proper solution is using `ElementRef`, which is really easy to understand, without using `@Hostbinding()` and `@Input()`

Comment: You wouldn't use renderer2 to set the src attr?